# Eclipse Referenced Libraries empty

Tags: eclipse, gradle

My Referenced Library folder is empty, it's not hidden or filtered, I can display it but it's just empty: https://ibb.co/q1nXNt0.

I think it happened after I tried to extract one of the .jar manually.

I don't know what to do to make it display the libraries again. Project's still working so the libraries themselves are still here but it's very annoying.

EDIT: of course I tried gradle clean and refresh gradle project to no avail.

EDIT2: I trried adding a new dependency and gradle does download it (I can see it in Windows Explorer).

EDIT3: I tried creating a new Spring Boot project and I have the same problem: the Referenced Libraries folder stays empty even when I add dependencies.